# Using message type as JSON, got error message during validation like "receive message payload was empty"

Tags: citrus-framework

Using the below code, i tried validating the mongodb data for name field but the test case failed with

```
20193 [main] INFO com.consol.citrus.Citrus -  FAILURE: Caused by: ValidationException: Unable to validate message elements - receive message payload was empty
```

Same test is passing if i comment out `.messageType(MessageType.JSON)` in the below code.

Please let me know your inputs on this error and also the steps to validate the output json message.

```
10491 [main] INFO com.consol.citrus.validation.xml.DomXmlMessageValidator - XML message validation successful: All values OK
10495 [main] INFO com.consol.citrus.validation.DefaultMessageHeaderValidator - Message header validation successful: All values OK

@CitrusTest
public void def_DI7381AndDI7383_CreateNamespace() {

    echo("----@CitrusTest Calling API services---- ");
    String strCname1="";
    String strId1="";

    http()
        .client(DIAPI)
        .send()
        .post("modeler/api/internal/namespace")
     // .name("todoRequest")
        .accept("application/json")
        .header("Content-type","application/json")
        .header("access","application/json")
        .payload(new ClassPathResource("updatedJsonFiles/NameSpace/UpdValidNameSpace.json"));
    //  .payload(new ClassPathResource("UpdValidNameSpace.json"));



    http()
        .client(DIAPI)
        .receive()
        .response(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    //  .messageType(MessageType.JSON)
    //  .payload(new ClassPathResource("updatedJsonFiles/NameSpace/UpdValidNameSpace.json"))
    //  .payload("citrus:jsonPath(citrus:message(todoRequest.payload()), '$..name')");
    //  .validate("$..id",id)
        .validate("$.name", strCname);
    //  .validate("$..namespaceId", namespaceId)
    //  .validate("$..description", description);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you leave out `.messageType(MessageType.JSON)` Citrus is using the default message type which is `XML`. This is why you see `XML message validation successful` in the logs.

As the XML message validator is not able to apply the given JsonPath expressions your test is green. So you need to use `.messageType(MessageType.JSON)`.

The root cause of your problem is that the system under test responds to the Http request with an empty message body. As you expect a message body in your validation Citrus raises the `ValidationException: Unable to validate message elements - receive message payload was empty`

So please make sure that your system under test is sending a proper JSON message body as response and your validation will perform as expected.